# Return an uploaded file for resubmission in MVC

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload

My use case is this:

1. User has a file to upload.
2. File is validated and various metadata is returned to the user.
3. User now decides whether to commit the file of not.

Part three is the *new bit*.  Currently the user just uploaded the file, it's committed and information about what happened is returned.  I'm having to put in the middle bit.

I've added a boolean `supressCommit` that allows the file to be uploaded, the information to be gathered but then the committing not to take place.

Now I have a problem, I don't want to introduce state on the server and store the file contents there.  That would open up a whole other can of worms.  This means that if the user clicks the commit button on the confirmation page I have to upload the file again, this time with `suppressCommit` set to `false`.

It's not pretty, but acceptable.  My problem is this though, how can I re-upload the original file without the user having to go through selecting the file again?

My options seem to be:

- Pass the file contents back in the model.

  - Not great as now I'll have to somehow put those into the HTTP request manually so they show in the `RequestContext` in the `Request.Files` collection.
- Pass back the original file path.

  - If I do this then is it possible to pragmatically set the File input box to something or is that a security violation?

Comment: You can't do this. A browser will upload a selected file only once, you can't control the form containing the file through JavaScript (as in: background upload) and the website (obviously) can't set the path for a `<input type="file" />` control.

Comment: why you don't save the uploaded file name for this session, and when it commits the upload, you already have the file on your server you can work on it, if not committed delete it, or empty the upload temp folder regularly.

Comment: I'd forgotten about Temp.  That will work without any problems.